# Symfony2 session lost after posting login form to login_check

Tags: session, symfony, authentication

Hi I have a static website running at localhost:8080/site. Here I display a login form. The form's action is project:8888/app_dev.php/login_check

My Symfony application, running at project:8888/app_dev.php/ also has it's own login form with the same action, at project:8888/app_dev.php/login

When I login using the login form in my Symfony application all works fine.

When I submit the login form on the static website, I get the following security error:

Your session has timed out, or you have disabled cookies

I assume this is a security matter, which makes it impossible to post login credentials from another domain? Is there a way to work around? Thanks in advance.